# php mail issue with godaddy

Tags: php, email

Okkkk...I don't know much about the PHP mail function so don't blast me for this. The problem is this...I'm hosting my own site using the freedns.afraid.org nameservers and when you go to my domain it redirects to my no-ip domain. I am hosting use xampp. I have my domain registered under godaddy and also my email. Here is how I have everything set up from my configs to my code. For reason unknown to me, I can't send emails! I probably have this whole thing messed up but I'm just asking for help.

php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = relay-hosting.secureserver.net
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 3535

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = account@godaddydomain.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

my sendmail config

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=relay-hosting.secureserver.net
smtp_port=3535
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=
auth_password=
force_sender=
```

my html and php test email code

```
<html>
<head><title>PHP Mail() test</title></head>
<body>
This form will attempt to send a test email. Please enter where this test should be sent to<br><p>
<form action = "mail.php" method = "post" name="sendmail">
Enter an email address: <input type = "text" name = "to"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit"><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset"><br><p>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['to'])) {
       $mail_to=$_POST['to'];
    $mail_subject="Test email from";
    $mail_body="This is a test email, sent from ";
    $header = "<admin@godaddydomain.com>";

    if(mail($mail_to, $mail_subject, $mail_body,$header,"-fadmin@godaddyadmin.com")) {
        print "Email sent successfully!";
    } else {
        print "Email did not send!!!!!";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Debug info

```
12/03/08 11:08:42 ** This is a test email, sent from 
12/03/08 11:08:42 ** --- MESSAGE END ---
12/03/08 11:08:42 ** Connecting to relay-hosting.secureserver.net:3535
12/03/08 11:08:52 ** Disconnected.
12/03/08 11:08:52 ** Disconnected.
12/03/08 11:08:52 ** Disconnected.
12/03/08 11:08:52 ** Disconnected.
12/03/08 11:08:52 ** Connect timed out.
12/03/08 11:29:18 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
12/03/08 11:29:18 ** To: bice64g@aim.com
```

Also I get this error

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at
>   "relay-hosting.secureserver.net" port 3535, verify your "SMTP" and
>   "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\mail.php on line 20

```
12/03/08 11:29:18 ** Subject: Test email from
12/03/08 11:29:18 ** Content-type: text/html
12/03/08 11:29:18 ** From: "PHP mail() Test Script"<noreply@>
12/03/08 11:29:18 ** 
12/03/08 11:29:18 ** This is a test email, sent from 
12/03/08 11:29:19 ** --- MESSAGE END ---
12/03/08 11:29:19 ** Connecting to relay-hosting.secureserver.net:3535
12/03/08 11:29:29 ** Disconnected.
12/03/08 11:29:29 ** Disconnected.
12/03/08 11:29:29 ** Disconnected.
12/03/08 11:29:29 ** Disconnected.
12/03/08 11:29:29 ** Connect timed out.
```

Comment: maybe space? -f admin...

Comment: Can you paste the output of `debug.log` here

Comment: godaddy is so slow anyway, it'll take you 15 mins to confirm the email was sent.  Why not use google apps w/ gmail?

Comment: @vigrond can you set up a custom domain address with your email with google apps? I'm just confused on how I would go about setting that whole thing up especially since I've made the obvious fatal mistake of getting my email with go daddy.

Comment: Yes, it's quite easy.  Go to https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/standard/new3 .  Register & confirm your domain, create your email address in the "Users" panel.  And wala, you can use gmail's SSL port / smtp.gmail.com and have fast great email, free.  Can be done in 5 mins.

Comment: You will also have to set up MX records in your domain management area of godaddy.  Set the MX records like so http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174125  so that mail is routed to google's servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you provided shows that you are attempting to use “relay-hosting.secureserver.net” as the relay server in your application. That address is a gateway for email leaving Go Daddy webhosting servers. It will not be available from a Go Daddy Dedicated server or from a personal server not located within a Go Daddy datacenter. If you are hosting this on a Go Daddy Virtual or Dedicated server you can get your personal relay server information from the Go Daddy support chat. If you are hosting this application outside of the Go Daddy network you will need to get the correct relay information from your hosting or network provider. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should comment out the `sendmail_path`... this is from the help http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path

> This directive works also under Windows. If set, smtp, smtp_port and
>   sendmail_from are ignored and the specified command is executed.

Also check the `debug.log` - there should be some pointers in there ...

Your header

```
$header = "<admin@godaddydomain.com>";
```

isnt valid, try something like :

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com';
```

Comment: Ok, now I get this error     - Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "relay-hosting.secureserver.net" port 3535, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\mail.php on line 20

Comment: haha at least something works I guess. Any advice for fixing the connection problems because I am stuck...

Comment: Contact your hosting company ! Sorry !!